# Strange behaviour of training accuracy and loss function

Tags: conv-neural-network, accuracy, tensorflow, keras, training-error

Firstly, I want to mention that I am not looking for suggestions to improve the training accuracy of my NN. The only purpose of this question is to know what might be causing the peculiar behaviour described herein.

My CNN was initially having an issue with the training accuracy that was stuck at 0.5467. I overcame this issue by using BatchNormalization. However, now it shows something weird. After a certain number of epochs, the accuracy sharply drops from around 0.9 to the earlier figure, i.e., 0.5467. I find this strange because:

1. The accuracy does not gradually decline; and
2. What is so special about '0.5467' that no matter what changes I make to the CNN (architecture, optimizer, or activation function) the training accuracy is always this specific number.
   Here is the plot of accuracy and loss:[image: plot]

I want to know if this a common issue among data scientists, and also if there are any clues to the probable causes.

Here is the architecture I have used, along with the model parameters:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())


model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())


model.add(Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt=keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Here is the quick model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_35 (Conv1D)           (None, 6, 16)             48        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_21 (Batc (None, 6, 16)             64        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_36 (Conv1D)           (None, 5, 8)              264       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_22 (Batc (None, 5, 8)              32        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_37 (Conv1D)           (None, 4, 4)              68        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (Batc (None, 4, 4)              16        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_38 (Conv1D)           (None, 4, 2)              10        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_24 (Batc (None, 4, 2)              8         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 4, 2)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_8 (Flatten)          (None, 8)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 10)                90        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_25 (Batc (None, 10)                40        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 44        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 5         
=================================================================
Total params: 689
Trainable params: 609
Non-trainable params: 80
_________________________________________________________________
```

Any hints or suggestions on this matter would be very helpful.